# what PIC microcontroller can detect a file from a USB flashdrive?

Tags: microcontroller, usb

Is there a PIC microcontroller that can read from a USB Flashdrive?

PICs are programmable, but can you write a program that enables you to check for a certain word in a certain file from a usb?

for example, in the flashdrive, theres a file named PASS.txt (written inside the file is "1234"). Now is it possible to program the microcontroller so that it can check for the "1234" inside the PASS.txt?

Comment: The answer is yes, if you can get the uC communicating with the flash drive in the first place, and decode whatever file structure is in place. It sounds like you're in over your head.

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually looking for is called a USB Host Mass Storage Controller. See this application note from Microchip for details:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01142A.pdf

I do not have any experience with PICs but I guess that all versions with built-in USB Host Support should be able to handle this.

Comment: And if it doesn't have built-in host support, and you're really skilled, you can *possibly* write a software USB-host.

Comment: I have a feeling that this isn't the way to OP should go :-)